# Is there a way to have "local-only" npm scripts so they aren't committed to repo?

Tags: git, webpack, package.json, npm-scripts

I'm developing a React project, which normally runs on port 3000. However, on my machine that port is used by a Windows service that I'll be using for other projects. So, in my **package.json** for this project, I have the following setting:

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "webpack serve --open --port 3012"
    // All the other scripts
}
```

I'm wondering, is there any way to have this particular port setting set local only? I don't want to commit this **package.json** to the repo with this and annoy other developers who probably don't have my same setup. I was thinking maybe a local-only **.json** that can be referenced *if* it exists, but I have no idea. This is really just for convenience as I know I will forget to add the "--port" option on the terminal and then I'll curse myself out as my computer goes "Durr, that port is in use already, dummy." Any suggestions/ideas?

Comment: I personally use the convention `name` and `name:dev` for my prod and local scripts.

Comment: Don't you just want _environment variables_, `PORT=3012`? The short answer to your question is: no, but there are other approaches.

Comment: You can ask git to **not** care about changes on a file by using `git update-index --assume-unchanged`. And, as you might have guessed, it's a local-only operation.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah, you're right, this is what I just needed to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who may have a similar idea or problem: environment variables. That's what you need to use.

Although in my case specifically I just removed the offending program, and will re-add it when I need it.